# Typescript usage of jest-when and mockResolvedValue

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript-typings, ts-jest

I'm trying to use jest-when to mock out requests made with Axios, but am having trouble with the Typescript typings when trying to use mockResolvedValue. See example snippets below:

```
jest.mock('axios')

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

// doesn't work
when(mockedAxios.get)
    .calledWith('http://some-api')
    .mockResolvedValue('foo'); // complains that "Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)"

// this seems to work w/ the generic type hint, but is super ugly...
when<Promise<unknown>, any[]>(mockedAxios.get)
    .calledWith('http://some-api')
    .mockResolvedValue('foo');
```

I think it might have something to do with `when(mockedAxios.get)` resolving to `WhenMock<unknown, [string, AxiosRequestConfig?]>` (T being unknown specifically), but am kinda stumped.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with jest-when and got. got has an overloaded signature and typescript only seems to allow one version of it with jest-when.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same proplem.

Comment: It's been a while now but I don't believe so... IIRC I just ended up sticking w/ the workaround using the generic type hint.